Why does pressing Ctrl + Q (align left in Spanish) on a paragraph that is already left aligned justify it?
In Spanish the keyboard shortcut to align the paragraph to the left is Ctrl+Q.
I use the Normal style, whose alignment is left.
Pressing Ctrl+Q on a left-aligned paragraph justifies it.
I don't know if the same thing will happen in English with Ctrl+L
What could it be due to?



I do not know. Does this happen in all documents? How about if you start Word in safe mode? https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72 -- I urge all users to not do direct formatting like this but rather to have styles that they use. It makes for much cleaner documents that are easier to edit and less prone to problems. -- https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm You may want to save a sample document that has the problem on OneDrive or DropBox and and a share link to your question. That way others can see if the problem can be reproduced.
